# Clicking submit button opens print preview

Tags: javascript, jquery

When clicking the submit button, within Chrome, the print preview window is opened just as it would if you pushed CTRL + P. I'm absolutely baffled. Also, nothing gets printed to the console even when text is entered into the 'myinput' input field.

**html**

```
                <div class="subscribeform">

                    <input class="myinput">

                    <input placeholder="Enter Email">

                    <button class="subscribesubmit1" type='submit'>
                        Submit
                    </button>

                </div>
```

**javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

          $('.subscribesubmit1').click(function() {

            var myinput = $('.myinput').val();
            print(myinput)

        });   

</script>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.subscribesubmit1').click(function() {
    var myinput = $('.myinput').val();
    console.log(myinput);
});
```

The print() method prints the contents of the current window. 
And if you are new to javascript id suggest that you don't jump straight to **jquery**